# How I can find the injected file or database which hacked by any one in vtiger crm 6.4?

Tags: virus, vtigercrm

I am using vtiger crm 6.4. for my product, I have taken source code from a developer who has customized my product in vtiger crm 6.4. So everytime from vtiger_users table, the admin password will change. I want to know what is the way to finding the script or what is the place the things will happening.

Comment: Since it's open source, a good start would be to run a diff with the original files to find the changes and then review them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use a php shell detector like [PHP-Shell-Detector](https://github.com/spadana2004/PHP-Shell-Detector) or install [cxs scanner](https://configserver.com/cp/cxs.html) or antivirus on your server

Comment: also you must change access_key for all users in vtiger_users table

Answer (score -1):

Most of developer using change password script to change the admin user's password and they keeps it in root folder. Try to search `vtiger_users` table in whole code of crm so that you will find the script where developer written query on `vtiger_users` table. Then find the specific script and delete it.